# How to create list to initialize object from user

Tags: .net

I'm just starting the adventure with .net and I'll just write a calculator.
I have created one view from which I get data from the user, model with data and a controler that calculates the equation for me. I would like to save the result in the list and then pass the result to the next view. Unfortunately, I am stuck on initializing the list. I am asking for advice on how a beginner can deal with this.
 There is My Model :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace CalculatorApp.Models
{
    public class Data
    {
        public float No1 { get; set; }
        public float No2 { get; set; }
        public float Wynik { get; set; }
        public string Znak { get; set; }

    }
}
```

There is my Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using CalculatorApp.Models;


namespace CalculatorApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index(Data data)
        {
            List<float> datas = new List<float>()
            {
                new float () {data.No1}
            };

            switch (data.Znak)
            {
                case "add":
                    data.Wynik = data.No1 + data.No2;
                    break;
                case "sub":
                    data.Wynik = data.No1 - data.No2;
                    break;
                case "mul":
                    data.Wynik = data.No1 * data.No2;
                    break;
                case "div":
                    data.Wynik = data.No1 / data.No2;
                    break;
            }
            return View("Index", data);


        }

        public ViewResult Wynik()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }      
}
```

And First View to get data:

```
@model Data


<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="widtht=device-width" />
    <title>Strona głowna</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="No1">No1:</label>
            <input asp-for="No1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="No2">No2:</label>
            <input asp-for="No2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="add" name="Znak" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="sub" name="Znak" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="mul" name="Znak" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="div" name="Znak" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit"asp-action="Wynik" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much for any information

Comment: Thank you for including the relevant code.  I'm unclear at which point you are experiencing trouble.  Can you provide more clarity?

Comment: idk how save Wynik to show it on next view

Answer (score 0):

When you hit submit on your form, MVC looks for an `[HttpPost]` action method in the controller, so add that above your Index action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Data data)
{
  //logic here
}
```

I am unsure why you are trying to initialize and populate a list though. You should be able to do your calculations in Index and then return that to the page without a list.

In that case you would need to update your Index view include something like this before the `<form>` element. You can retrieve values from the model passed to the View using `@Model.[PROPERTY_NAME_HERE]`:

```
<div id="DisplayResult">
   <p>@Model.Wynik</p>
</div>
<form ...> ...
```

Comment: When i try do this data.Wynik (Cannot initialize type "float" with aa collection initiaalizer because does not implement  'System.Collection.IEnumerbale'
`
            List<float> datas = new List<float>()
            {
                new float () {data.Wynik}
            };`

Comment: It works, thank you very much for your help. But unfortunately I still don't understand how to use the Letter in the future so if someone would have moments I would like to explain

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean when you ask "how to use the Letter". Can you clarify? Also, as I stated before, you should be able to remove all the `List<float>` code in your `Index()` action method and still have your calculator work